# Why do these identical limits give different results?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 12.0.0.0. and persisting through 13.3.0.0.**

---

I wanted to calculate this limit:

```
 Limit[E^(E^ProductLog[n] (-1 + E^(1/2 Sqrt[ProductLog[n]/n]))) (1 + 1/2 Sqrt[1/(n*ProductLog[n])])^-n, n -> Infinity]
```

The correct result is `E^(1/8)`

[image: correct limit]

Furthermore, it is true that

```
 Limit[(E^(-(1/2) E^(ProductLog[n]/2)))/ (1 + 1/2 Sqrt[1/(n*ProductLog[n])])^-n, n -> Infinity]
```

is equal to `1`
[image: true limit]

Therefore, it must be

```
 Limit[E^(E^ProductLog[n] (-1 + E^(Sqrt[ProductLog[n]]/(2 Sqrt[n]))))*(E^(-(1/2) E^(ProductLog[n]/2))) , n -> Infinity]
```

also equal to `E^(1/8)`
But the result shocked me. **Mathematica gives Infinity !!!**

[image: wrong limit]

The graph confirms my original assumption

```
 Plot[E^(E^ProductLog[n] (-1 + E^(Sqrt[ProductLog[n]]/(2 Sqrt[n]))))*(E^(-(1/2) E^(ProductLog[n]/2))) , {n, 1, 1000000}]
```

[image: graph]

On deeper analysis, I was able to better isolate the problem and have the following simpler example.

```
 Limit[-(1/2) Sqrt[n/ProductLog[n]] + ((-1 + E^(1/(2 Sqrt[n/ProductLog[n]]))) n)/ ProductLog[n], n -> Infinity]
```

again gives the wrong result of **Infinity**

[image: wrong limit]

The limit is equal to `1/8`, which is supported by the following graph

```
 Plot[-(1/2) Sqrt[n/ProductLog[n]] + ((-1 + E^(1/(2 Sqrt[n/ProductLog[n]]))) n)/ ProductLog[n], {n, 1, 1000000}]
```

[image: tends to 1/8]

Comment: It depends on the version. The bug is in versions 12 and 13. Versions 10.2 and 11.0 calculate the limits correctly.

Comment: Please report to Wolfram Technical Support <support@wolfram.com>.

Comment: Do you have a question? It's not clear to me what you're asking for help with.

Comment: Question is in the title: Why do these identical limits give different results?

Comment: What do you mean, "why?" Do you want to know where the computation goes differently internally? That is, a comparison of the codes in the different versions? You should ask Wolfram about that. You seem to know the correct answer and you call it a bug in a comment. What more do you want to know?

Comment: If it has been determined that these examples indicates a `Limit` bug, and it remains in version 13.1, someone please send a report providing a clear specification of the problem.

Comment: fyi, I checked V 13.2, and it still gives $\infty$

Comment: Thank you for testing.

Comment: Someone might want to send a bug report with a minimal example.

Comment: Still a bug in 13.3.0.

Comment: And still no bug report. Might or might not be a coincidence.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way, by a limited approach corresponding to approaching positive infinity:

```
expr = -(1/2) Sqrt[
     n/ProductLog[n]] + ((-1 + E^(1/(2 Sqrt[n/ProductLog[n]]))) n)/
    ProductLog[n];

Limit[expr /. n -> 1/n, n -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]

(*  1/8  *)
```

Another workaround:

```
Limit[SeriesCoefficient[expr, {n, Infinity, 0}], n -> Infinity]

(*  1/8  *)
```

Possible cause of trouble:

The series at infinity seems divergent:

```
sd = Series[expr, {n, Infinity, 2}];
seriescoeffs = sd[[3]];
firstnumerator = sd[[4]];
denominator = sd[[6]];

kk = firstnumerator - 1;
(++kk; a[kk] (n^(kk/denominator)) -> 
    Limit[Simplify[# (n^(kk/denominator))], 
     n -> Infinity]) & /@ seriescoeffs
(*
{a[-1]/Sqrt[n] -> 0,
 a[0]          -> 1/8,
 Sqrt[n] a[1]  -> \[Infinity], 
 n a[2]        -> \[Infinity],
 n^(3/2) a[3]  -> \[Infinity], 
 n^2 a[4]      -> \[Infinity]}
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

A partial workaround.

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[n_] = -(1/2) Sqrt[
     n/ProductLog[n]] + ((-1 + E^(1/(2 Sqrt[n/ProductLog[n]]))) n)/
    ProductLog[n] // FullSimplify

(* -(1/2) Sqrt[E^ProductLog[n]] + 
 E^ProductLog[n] (-1 + E^(1/(2 Sqrt[E^ProductLog[n]]))) *)
```

Using [`Asymptotic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Asymptotic.html)

```
asymp = Asymptotic[f[n], n -> Infinity] // Simplify[#, n > 1] &;

Limit[asymp, n -> Infinity]

(* 1/8 *)
```

Or using [`Series`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html)

```
ser = Series[f[n], {n, Infinity, 1}] //
    Normal // Simplify[#, n > 1] &;

Limit[ser, n -> Infinity]

(* 1/8 *)
```

Comment: Interesting that this gave me infinity: `Series[expr, {n, Infinity, 1}] // Normal // Simplify //  Limit[#, n -> Infinity] &` b/c `expr` wasn't simplified.