# How to calculate these limits with the LambertW function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

For `p>=2` I need to calculate a limit

```
 With[{p = 2}, Limit[E^(ProductLog[n p]/p)*(E^(-n^(-1 + 1/p) p^(-2 + 1/p) ProductLog[n p]^(1 - 1/p)) + 1/p - 1) + E^ProductLog[n p]/ p*(E^(-n^(-1 + 1/p) p^(-1 + 1/p) ProductLog[n p]^(1 - 1/p)) - 1), n -> Infinity]]
```

[image: Limit]

The limit is returned unevaluated.

Unfortunately, my efforts so far have stalled on finding a bug in Mathematica (versions 12 and 13), see
[Why do these identical limits give different results?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270541/why-do-these-identical-limits-give-different-results)

Then I found out that versions 10 and 11 don't have this bug. So I continued with them. However, I can't get a result.

My conjecture is that the limit is equal to `-1/4` for `p=2` and is equal to zero for `p>=3`.

```
 With[{p = 2}, Plot[E^(ProductLog[n p]/p)*(E^(-n^(-1 + 1/p) p^(-2 + 1/p) ProductLog[n p]^(1 - 1/p)) + 1/p - 1) + E^ProductLog[n p]/p*(E^(-n^(-1 + 1/p) p^(-1 + 1/p) ProductLog[n p]^(1 - 1/p)) - 1), {n, 1, 100000000000}]]
```

[image: p=2]

```
 With[{p = 3}, Plot[E^(ProductLog[n p]/p)*(E^(-n^(-1 + 1/p) p^(-2 + 1/p) ProductLog[n p]^(1 - 1/p)) + 1/p - 1) + E^ProductLog[n p]/p*(E^(-n^(-1 + 1/p) p^(-1 + 1/p) ProductLog[n p]^(1 - 1/p)) - 1), {n, 1, 100000000000}]]
```

[image: p=3]

My question is: How to calculate these limits with Mathematica ?

Versions 10 and 11 are able to calculate a similar limit

```
 Limit[E^(E^ProductLog[n] (-1 + E^(Sqrt[ProductLog[n]]/(2 Sqrt[n]))))*(E^(-(1/2) E^(ProductLog[n]/2))) , n -> Infinity]
```

[image: similar limit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After substitution
$$t=\frac{n}{W(p n)}$$
we have
$$W(p n)=\frac{n}{t}$$
and
$$\exp(W(p n))=\frac{p n}{W(p n)}=p t$$
where W is the LambertW function.
Now the expression transforms to

```
 (-1 + E^(-p^(-1 + 1/p) t^(-1 + 1/p))) t + (-1 + E^(-p^(-2 + 1/p) t^(-1 + 1/p)) + 1/p) p^(1/p) t^(1/p)
```

If `n` tends to infinity, `t` also tends to infinity and as a result we get

```
 Assuming[p > 2, Limit[(-1 + E^(-p^(-1 + 1/p) t^(-1 + 1/p))) t + (-1 + E^(-p^(-2 + 1/p) t^(-1 + 1/p)) + 1/p) p^(1/p) t^(1/p), t -> Infinity]]
```

[image: limits]

My conjecture is proven.

Comment: Math beats Mathematica! :)

Answer (score 6):

Using my first approach from [Why do these identical limits give different results?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270541/why-do-these-identical-limits-give-different-results/270545#270545) —

```
With[{p = 2}, 
 expr = E^(ProductLog[n p]/
        p)*(E^(-n^(-1 + 1/p) p^(-2 + 1/p) ProductLog[
            n p]^(1 - 1/p)) + 1/p - 1) + 
    E^ProductLog[n p]/
      p*(E^(-n^(-1 + 1/p) p^(-1 + 1/p) ProductLog[n p]^(1 - 1/p)) - 
       1) // FullSimplify]

Limit[expr /. n -> 1/n, n -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]

(*  -(1/4)  *)
```

(Did you try it on this? You left no comment. With `p = 3`, I get `0`, too.)

Comment: This is a valuable result for me that confirms my conjectures. Thank you! But this only works under version 13. Under version 10 (which I have more confidence in after yesterday) I get an error message: "Limit::ldir: Value of Direction -> FromAbove should be a number or Automatic. >>"

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec Follow the hint in the error message, and, consulting the docs, replace `"FromAbove"` with `-1`, IIRC.  Then see if it works. I can no longer test such an old version as V10. (BTW, `p = 4` has been running for a half hour or more with no answer yet. It probably won't finish.)

Comment: Yes, it works now even under version 10..

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec Good. I was afraid there was a real change in what Limit could do.

Comment: Interesting situation: cases `p=5`, `p=6` and `p=7` (all with a result of 0) ended in 2-3 minutes each. The `p=4` and `p=8` cases have been running for over 13 hours now and each consumes over 60 GB of RAM (on my 384 GB server). Only integer `p` are interesting to me, but I can also add that the cases `p=5/2`, `p=7/2`, `p=9/2` and `p=11/2` also ended with a result of zero in just a few minutes.

Comment: I aborted the calculation for `p=4` after 46 hours. The program consumed 143 GB of RAM and still not finished.